# Python Dataframe: How to get alphabetically ordered list of column names

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, field

I currently am able to get a list of all the column names in my dataframe using:

```
df_EVENT5.columns.get_values()
```

But I want the list to be in alphabetical order ... how do I do that?

Comment: What is your end-goal - a numpy array or a Vanilla Python list?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the list of column names in alphabetical order, try:

```
df_EVENT5.columns.sort_values().values
```

Comment: I have a df where one column is named None - but not "None". The other columns are strings. sort_values() returns an error in this case. (This is not a problem I need to solve, but it popped up while I was messing with this question.)

Comment: @Evan, try this: `df.columns.fillna('N/A').sort_values().values`